# Child's game where a picture behind a shutter is only visible for a split second

Tags: identify-this-game

I'm looking for the name of a children's game where a picture behind a plastic shutter is visible only for a fraction of a second. The players sitting in front of the shutter then had to guess the picture.

I'm not looking for the game where single parts of a picture are revealed one after the other. The game I have in mind had a simple plastic mechanic, which opened and quickly closed again a shutter while making some clattering noises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the game I had in mind. However, the picture is not revealed by a shutter as I originally asked, but by a rotating pole. The cluttering sound is simply induced by the plastic arm moving around.

The game from 1997 is called „**Flip-Flap**“ and published in Germany by „Ravensburger“.

[image: Flip Flap]